# Laravel 5.7 getting all the siblings for each child

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I wonder how to get all the sibling that a child have in laravel model ?

I know i can use this `$siblings = \App\Child::all()->where('parent_id', $parent_id)->where('id', $id);` to get all the child siblings, but I want to know if I can do the other way or more cleanest way? 
So you can call this in the blade view `$child->siblings->full_name` something like that.

But I wonder how to use it something like this in the model.php

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

with only using the `belongsTo` or `hasMany` function maybe if it's possible?

Sorry I'm not good with english so I don't know what it's called so I can search it on google.

Edit:: Adding Child.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Child extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $dates = [
        'birthdate',
        'father_birthdate',
        'mother_birthdate',
        'guardian_birthdate',
    ];

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    // I want to call this function only using $child->siblings (this one will show all the siblings)
    // without passing the parent id
    // to make it cleaner
    public function siblings($parent_id)
    {
        return $this->all()->where('parent_id', $parent_id);
    }

    public function getAgeAttribute()
    {
        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['birthdate'])->age;
    }

    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['first_name'] . ' ' . $this->attributes['last_name'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you could do this.

1 creating the below method:

```
public function sibling()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class)->where('parent_id', $this->parent_id);
}
```

2 using a single Query:

```
$siblings = \App\Child::where('parent_id', $parent_id)->get();
```

Hope this helps

**Update**

A third way is:

```
public function scopeSiblings($query, $parent_id) {

    return $query->where('parent_id', $parent_id)->get();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think I can do that in the first way, because it's for the same table, I already updated my question, you can see the full file there

Comment: The `all()` will cause performance issues and so will take longer to process. Also you will need to call that as `$child->siblings()

Comment: but I want to get all the child siblings, is there another way to approach this? with the lowest costs?

Comment: What you are doing with all()is getting mysql to get all of the records in the table then using php to filfter the records.

Comment: but doesn't this code `$this->all()->where('parent_id', $parent_id)` similar with `SELECT * FROM child WHERE parent_id = $id`?

Comment: You can have a look for yourself by using this code before the query \DB::enableQueryLog(); and the place this after your query logger(\DB::getQueryLog() ); and this will output the raw SQL that is used in your Laravel Logs